# Read in array from external array [JS file]

Tags: javascript, arrays, parsing, external

I want to modify this code, to instead read the - currenly commented - array from a "arrays.js"

```
<head><meta charset="UTF-8"><style>
div {text-align: left;}
h1 {font-size: 11px;font-family: Arial;}
button {width: 128px;height: 28px;background-color: white;color: black;}
{font-size: 11px;}
button:hover{background-color: white;}
</style></head><body>
<script src="arrays.js"></script>
<div><button onclick="generateQuote();">CurrListen</button><p id="quoteOutput"></div>
<script>

         //const arrayOfQuotes = [
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Od4sH0vVFpI">Musique pour la tristesse de Xion - KHIII (Yoko Shimomura)</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=cqAawjQyieg">Kellys Lullaby - Another Code R - Satoshi Okubo</a>'},
        {'quote': 'Nears Theme - Death Note OST III - Hideki Taniuchi'},
        {'quote': 'Abandon Me - Chicory OST - Lena Raine'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xJMWAM--ePM">Vector to the Heavens - KH3582 OST - Yoko Shimomura</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=Yf6Eqze6sMM">Forgotten Legend - Gyakuten Saiban 4 OST - Toshihiko Horiyama</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=Y20l0tW9VfQ">Solitude - Amagi Brilliant Park - Shinkichi Mitsumune</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=FVSkRipU2oE">Girl of catching Theme - Speed Grapher OST I - Shinkichi Mitsumune</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=R7jhnVdLz50">Esperanto - RZero Physis OST - Luna Umegaki</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=yFabSBzC068">Ai wa kurayami no naka de - ZARD</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://youtube.com/watch?v=XU8j5TGaX8g&list=PLJXkRwmABZWQxfi-uKuEgGrY31RUWRmvv&index=7">Tranc</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oCF_leSNIfA&list=PL0bj_3nLaCVwfKoGJX8AeTJKYfGNgFq0D&index=18">Blue Indigo</a>'},
        {'quote': '<a target="_blank" href="https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PTKl17TXqyo&list=PLLiHaMFYDWBTFMLdgVBKUPxW2vs0WlAKL&index=1">Lily - Ender Lilies</a>'},
        ];

function generateQuote(){const random = Number.parseInt(Math.random()*arrayOfQuotes.length + 1);
document.querySelector('#quoteOutput').innerHTML = `\"${arrayOfQuotes[random].quote}\"`;}
</script>
</body>
```

I defined `<script src="arrays.js"></script>` beforehand,
but it fails to work.

What is needed to get this to function ?

More Declaration ?
A special new formatting ?

Comment: You got `<script src="arrays.js"></script>` inside the `style` tag. Move the javascript outside of it.

Comment: Your `<script>` tag is inside `<style>` tag so it's not interpreted as script, that's why it'snot working

Comment: I fixed the issue. However I still am unable to load the array from external...

Comment: Edit: This is my "workaround" solution https://jsfiddle.net/aoikurayami/1yhjods7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arrays.js`

```
const arrayOfQuotes = [
  // ...
];
window.arrayOfQuotes = arrayOfQuotes
```

Comment: Are you sure that `<script src="arrays.js"></script>` is actually present in your html?

Comment: With this method, you need to read `window.arrayOfQuotes`, not `arrayOfQuotes`, where you want to use the variable. Or you can do `const arrayOfQuotes = window.arrayOfQuotes` in your own script for convenience

Comment: @AndyRay you don't have to add `window.` to access window properties

Comment: Well... https://jsfiddle.net/aoikurayami/m9dgwa04/1/ I think it's still missing something

Comment: What about » const arrayOfQuotes = require('./arrays.js'); « ?

Comment: `require` doesn't work in browsers. You could use `import`

Comment: So... which solution will work in my usecase then ? Import ? The one @AndyRay proposed ? I still haven't found a way to pull in the array into the html from the array.js ...